# make an array of arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

so I've been having trouble with my code, specifically where I have these arrays:

```
var messageIntents = ["Send a message", "Send message", "Text", "Send text", "Send a text"]
var weatherIntents = ["weather", "what's the weather", "how's the weather", "the weather"]
var musicIntents = ["play", "i want to hear", "shuffle"]
```

The goal is to check to see if a string is equal to one of the values in the arrays. Rather than check these arrays one by one, I would like to make an array of arrays to check them all. Is that possible? And how would I check it?

Comment: `let intents = [messageIntents, weatherIntents, musicIntents]` for an array of arrays

Comment: Then would that work for checking arrays?

Comment: Update your question to say what you mean by checking the arrays?  Are you checking to see if a value is included?

Comment: Just updated it now, yes- to check for a value

Comment: `let intents = messageIntents + weatherIntents + musicIntents` for a single array with all elements, then `if intents.contains("Send message") { print("found it!") }`

Comment: I tried that but then got this error:                 Cannot use instance member 'messageIntents' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: put the code to initialize the intents array into a function

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the array inside of array like this [[Any]].

```
    var messageIntents = ["Send a message", "Send message", "Text", "Send text", "Send a text"]
    var weatherIntents = ["weather", "what's the weather", "how's the weather", "the weather"]
    var musicIntents = ["play", "i want to hear", "shuffle"]
```

Below an example of arrays inside of array placeholder.

```
    var arraysOfArray = [messageIntents, weatherIntents,musicIntents]
```

You can access object by each looping the index of an array

```
arraysOfArray[index]
arraysOnArray[0] //prints ["Send a message", "Send message", "Text", "Send text", "Send a text"]
```

or using 'for each' statement like this

```
for array in arraysOfArray{
    print(array)
   for dataObject in array{
    print(dataObject)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your array of strings in an array as well.
If your goal is to find a matching string within an array just use the contains function of Array.

```
var messageIntents = ["Send a message", "Send message", "Text", "Send text", "Send a text"]
var weatherIntents = ["weather", "what's the weather", "how's the weather", "the weather"]
var musicIntents = ["play", "i want to hear", "shuffle"]

let arrayOfArrays = [messageIntents, weatherIntents, musicIntents ]

let stringToFind = "weather"
for array in arrayOfArrays {
   if array.contains(stringToFind) {
      print("Found It")
      break
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that, you intend to categorize a string. If you intend to **directly compare** them ( by direct compare i mean no transformation during checking like `hasPrefix`, `hasSuffix`, `contains`, `toLowerCase`, `toUpperCase` ), then using a dictionary is the fastest way.

To do it in a cleaner way first of all declare an enum for categories

```
enum IntentCategories {
    case message
    case weather
    case music
    case none
}
```

Then storing the string keys in dictionary like following

```
var intents [String: IntentCategories] = [
                                          "Send a message" :  IntentCategories.message,
                                          "Send message"   :  IntentCategories.message,
                                          "Text"           :  IntentCategories.message,
                                          "weather"        :  IntentCategories.weather
                 //... insert all the intents for message, hope you get my point                 
                ]
```

Then finding the string checking for particular intent category

```
switch intents[INPUT_STRING] {
    case message:
         print("Message type intent detected")
    case weather:
         print("weather type intent detected")
    case music:
         print("music type intent detected")
    case none:
         print("undefined intent detected")
}
```

This implementation will give you the fastest possible way to categorize your intent strings.

If you need transformation of existing intent before comparing, there is no quick way except linearly searching each intent strings.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap()` to convert a 2D array into a 1D one, and check if that array contains the searched string:

```
[messageIntents, weatherIntents, musicIntents].flatMap { $0 }.contains(searchedString)
```

Or, you can use `contains(where:)` over the 2D array, and `contains()` on the inner arrays:

```
[messageIntents, weatherIntents, musicIntents].contains { $0.contains(searchedString) }
```